# Use varwidth to make a paragraph center in a table

Tags: tables, memoir, varwidth

The following code does what I want, except the `V` acts like the `p` option, but I want the `m` option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lV{2in}}\hline
Cat & Animal\newline Cute\newline Very furry\newline Spotted\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If I use `m` I have to manually figure out the length of the longest item in the second column, but the word "Cat" is vertically centered like I want it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lm{2in}}\hline
Cat & Animal\newline Cute\newline Very furry\newline Spotted\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here's what they look like:

[image: Both examples, left is m right is V]

I only found the `V` option via an [Internet search](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-varwidcol); the `varwidth` manual is surprising sparse.

How do I get a table option that combines `array`'s `m` and `varwidth`'s `V`? (I'm actually using `memoir`'s implementation of `array` if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.3 of 2021-10-18) supports the `V` columns of `varwidth` *with an optional argument*, between square brackets `m`, `p` or `b` for the vertical position. So, you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lV[m]{2in}}\hline
Cat & Animal\newline Cute\newline Very furry\newline Spotted\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

*Remark*: The letter `V` supports also the keys `r`, `l` and `c` for the horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't know that `varwidth` defines the `V` column type. Now I know! `;-)`.

Its definition is

```
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{%
  >{\begin{varwidth}[t]{#1}\narrowragged\let\\\tabularnewline}%
  l%
  <{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\end{varwidth}}}
```

so you should get what you want by

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{%
  >{\begin{varwidth}{#1}\narrowragged\let\\\tabularnewline\strut}%
  l%
  <{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\end{varwidth}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lM{2in}}\hline
Cat & Animal\newline Cute\newline Very furry\newline Spotted\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Notice that `memoir` loads `array` (actually it has code to that effect); with other classes it will be necessary to add

```
\usepackage{array}
```

[image]

Comment: Yay! This works, though I was getting some really weird stuff until I realized I hadn't copied the `\makeatletter` part!

Comment: @bombcar That's implicit in `.sty` files, so it wasn't there to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but does this answer give you the desired output?  If so, I guess the question is then whether the syntax works for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\newline}
\setstackgap{L}{13pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}\hline
Cat & \Centerstack[l]{Animal\newline Cute\newline Very furry\newline Spotted}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `stackengine`? I don't have it. The normal `l` enviroment doesn't do what I want with very long lines such as "Incredibly awesomely furry and powerful".

Comment: @bombcar See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine for download.